# MVC3 or 4 Comment box Tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I’m looking for a tutorial on how to add a comment box to the end of an articles page on one of my sites. Examples of this can be found at the bottom of many web pages on the net, including all the tutorials on the www.asp.net site and www.codeproject.com, I don’t need anything as complex as code project, I just need to be able to put a blog post, a list of comments and a comment box all on the one page in MVC3 or 4.

I have been searching high and low and can’t find a way to do this in MVC3 or 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I worked it out! And now a little extra text so the post is long enough to post!

Cheers,

Mike,